# Make Button inside TextField in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I made a `TextField` in `FXML`. I want to add `Button` in this `TextField` like clear button. How can I implement this?

Comment: Why don't you add the `Button` next to the `TextField`? You really need to have it inside the `TextField`?

Comment: yes..actually its client demand.By the way adding next to text field is very easy.I have done with that.

Answer (score 9):

You could use an `AnchorPane` to wrap the `TextField` and the `Button` and set the anchors to have the `TextField` to fill the entire `AnchorPane` and the `Button` to be anchored to the right-side.

**Example:**

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="322.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
  <children>
    <TextField prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    <Button graphicTextGap="0.0" minHeight="10.0" minWidth="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="22.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7085FF;&#10;-fx-background-radius: 30;&#10;-fx-background-insets: 0;" text="x" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="4.0">
      <font>
        <Font size="9.0" />
      </font>
    </Button>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

*The output is like:*

[image]

If you need it more than once (and most probably you will), it is a good idea to have it separately in another FXML file with the corresponding controller class that also handles the action of the `Button`.

**Example with separated FXML:**

*ButtonedTextField.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.ButtonedTextField">
  <children>
    <TextField fx:id="textField" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    <Button fx:id="button" graphicTextGap="0.0" minHeight="10.0" minWidth="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="22.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7085FF;&#10;-fx-background-radius: 30;&#10;-fx-background-insets: 0;" text="x" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="4.0">
      <font>
        <Font size="9.0" />
      </font>
    </Button>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

*ButtonedTextField.java* (controller)

```
public class ButtonedTextField implements Initializable {

    public @FXML TextField textField;
    private @FXML Button button;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        button.setOnAction(e -> textField.setText(""));
    }

}
```

And then you can include this control to another FXML:

*ButtonedTextFieldTest.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TabPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.ButtonedTextFieldTest">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
          <children>
            <fx:include fx:id="buttonedTextField" source="ButtonedTextField.fxml" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

*ButtonedTextFieldTest.java* (controller of including FXML)

```
public class ButtonedTextFieldTest implements Initializable {

    private @FXML AnchorPane buttonedTextField;
    private @FXML ButtonedTextField buttonedTextFieldController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        buttonedTextFieldController.textField.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            System.out.println(newVal);
        });

    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- You can customize the `Button` as you wish (maybe it is the easier to set the graphic)
- The placement and the styling can be further customized.
- As you can see in the last class, the control itself and its controller can be also injected! The convention is to have the controller injected is to use the "Controller" postfix after the ID of the inected control.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the `CustomTextField` class from the [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) project for this kind of functionality before. ControlsFX lacks good documentation, but the `CustomTextField` class is quite easy to use:

```
CustomTextField textfield = new CustomTextField
textfield.setRight(new Button());
```

Comment: ,In case of removing this button ,how do I remove this button from CustomTextField ?